# Hibernate many-to-many with additional params

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

Good day! I have two classes User and Achievement. User has a lot of achievement and achievement can be obtained by many users.
Any examples I have found use user_achievement table with only two columns - user_id and achievement_id. But I want to store on this table some extra params - for example, a date when user obtain an achievement.
How can I do it using hibernate-xml configuration?

Comment: Add more columns to each table to store the extra params.

Comment: How can it help? Extra params do not refer to user or achievement but to a pair of user and achievement.

Comment: Then add the columns to the user_achievement table.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another entity `AchievementInstance`, then you can have `OneToMany` relationship between the `User` and this entity. `AchievementInstance` has a date and any other additional field needed and also a `ManyToOne` relationship with `Achievement` entity.

```
@Entity
class User {
 @OneToMany
 List<AchievementInstance> achievements;
}

@Entity
class AchievementInstance {
 @ManyToOne
 Achievement achievement;
 ...
 Date date;
}

@Entity
class Achievement {
 ...
}
```